# Can a Perl module distribution include a script

Tags: perl, module

I'm considering of using modules to group scripts. I often end up in the scenario that I have one or more scripts that uses a certain module.

Is it possible to pack the scripts together with the module?

Are there any specifics to how to achieve that?

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Can you provide an examaple?

Comment: rephrased, I'd like to include scripts in a module directory managed through a local CPAN which would then when deploying the module become available for execution. Don't know if compilation will object to the presence of those scripts and in addition the scripts location will not be in the PATH.

Comment: See my answer below. The method I've shown will install your scripts into a location in `PATH`, and install the module into the proper location at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include scripts along with your module by including the `EXE_FILES` directive in a `Makefile.PL` file, and supplying the relative path to the scripts in an array reference. In the below example, the scripts live in a `bin/` directory within the top level of your module's directory. You do not need to have your files in a distribution-like layout, but it helps (see below).

After setting up your directory structure and fiddling with the paths within the `Makefile.PL`, running `make install` will install your scripts along with your module.

```
use ExtUtils::MakeMaker;

WriteMakefile(
    NAME              => 'My::Module',
    VERSION_FROM      => 'lib/My/Module.pm',
    ($] >= 5.005 ?
      (ABSTRACT_FROM  => 'lib/My/Module.pm',
    AUTHOR            => 'My Name <email.addr>') : ()),
    LIBS              => [],
    EXE_FILES         => [qw(bin/script1 bin/script2)],
    DEFINE            => '',
    INC               => '-I.',
    PREREQ_PM         => {},
);
```

Personally, I'd recommend turning your module into a full-blown distribution. Here's an example. First, install [Module::Starter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Starter), then:

```
module-starter --author="My Name" --email="my@email.com" --module=My::Module --eumm
```

Now you can copy your module's code to `lib/My/Module.pm`, create a `bin/` directory, put your scripts in it, add the `EXE_FILES` directive to the `Makefile.PL`, and you can use the full suite of `make` commands to make, test and install your modules and the scripts, eg:

```
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
make install
```

Here's a real-world [example](https://metacpan.org/source/STEVEB/RPi-WiringPi-1.00/Makefile.PL), one of my own distributions on the CPAN that includes a bundled `pinmap` Perl script along with the distribution's modules:

Comment: Thanks, will try this. We already use module-starter so this should be a nice extension to our procedure.